# What exactly are order statistics?

Tags: sampling, random-variable, order-statistics

Suppose $X_1,X_2,X_3.....X_n$ are random sample taken from a population.
Then Y(1)<Y(2)<Y(3).....<Y(n) are called order statistics written in increasing order by magnitude where:

Y(1)=minimum($X_1,X_2,X_3.....X_n$)

Y(n)=maximum($X_1,X_2,X_3.....X_n$)

Now the questions are:

1. How can we find the minimum and maximum of random variable/sample as it's a function, it's not a single number.
2. Maybe there is a hint that r.v. are sorted by magnitude. Then what is magnitude of a random variable.
   Please explain with real examples.

Comment: Can you expand on why you cannot find the minimum or maximum of a function? This seem false *prima facie* because of the existence of [mathematical optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization) in which functions are often minimized or maximized.

Comment: The magnitude of a random variable is similar to magnitudes of deterministic variables. For example, the standard deviation is a  2-norm on a random variable. $S_x = \sqrt{\mathbb{E}| X- \mathbb{E}[X] |^2} = \sqrt{\mathbb{E}[ X- \mathbb{E}[X] ]^2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can we find the minimum and maximum of random variable/sample as it's a function, it's not a single number.

- **As a number** The maximum of a sample is the highest number of a sample. This is a single number.
- **As a function** But, when we consider the sample as a random variable that can take *different values* with different probabilities, then the maximum becomes a random variable that can take different values with different probabilities.

  In this case we can describe the maximum with a function that described this probability for a specific value. (and the same for other order statistics)

---

Example: say you roll two six sided dices and you consider the highest value.

- For and particular roll the maximum is the highest number of the roll. For example, if you roll '4' and '1', then the maximum is '4'.
- For the *distribution* of the possible rolls of the maximum we compute the probabilities for a particular maximum. This will be the probability as function of the value of the maximum.

  The figure below shows the maximum as function of the two dice rolls

  $$ \begin{array}{c|cccccc}
  &\color{red}1 & \color{orange}2  & \color{gold} 3 & \color{green} 4 & \color{blue}5 &\color{purple} 6 \\
  \hline 
  \color{red}1&\color{red} 1 & \color{orange}2 & \color{gold} 3 & \color{green}4 & \color{blue}5 &\color{purple} 6\\
  \color{orange}2&\color{orange}2 &\color{orange} 2 & \color{gold} 3 & \color{green}4 & \color{blue}5 &\color{purple} 6\\
  \color{gold} 3&\color{gold} 3 & \color{gold} 3 & \color{gold} 3 &\color{green} 4 & \color{blue}5 & \color{purple}6\\
  \color{green}4&\color{green}4 & \color{green}4 & \color{green}4 &\color{green} 4 &\color{blue} 5 & \color{purple}6\\
  \color{blue}5&\color{blue}5 &\color{blue} 5 &\color{blue} 5 &\color{blue} 5 &\color{blue} 5 &\color{purple} 6\\
  \color{purple}6&\color{purple}6 &\color{purple} 6 & \color{purple}6 &\color{purple} 6 & \color{purple}6 & \color{purple}6\\
  \end{array}$$

  Then you can see that the probability that the maximum is $1$ is $\frac{1}{36}$, the probability that the maximum is $2$ is $\frac{3}{36}$, the probability that the maximum is $3$ is $\frac{5}{36}$, and so on.

  We can describe it as a function

  $$ \mathbb{P}(\text{max(2 six sided dice rolls)} = k)  = \frac{2k-1}{36}$$

Comment: Did you type out all those LaTeX color commands, or use a script? It is a nice aesthetic touch.

Comment: @Galen sometimes I use a script but in this case it is much faster without using a script. (unless you call ctrl+c,ctrl+v using a script)

Comment: Yes, sometimes manual editing is most expedient.  But for the record--for those who wish to emulate such $\TeX$ arrays--an `R` solution is `cols <- c("", paste0("\\color{", c("red", "orange", "gold", "green", "blue", "purple"), "}"));
s <- outer(0:6, 0:6, function(i,j) {k <- pmax(i,j); paste0(cols[k+1], ifelse(k > 0, k, ""))});
cat(paste(apply(s, 1, paste0, collapse=" & "), collapse="\\\\\n"))`

Comment: The second paragraph of this answer is potentially confusing.  The sample has to be considered a *vector-valued* function.  The maximum, minimum, or indeed the entire array of order statistics are then (continuous) functions of those vector values.